# UITableView requires double tap - but not first time

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, uiview

I have an UITableView, with cells that you can tap on.
When you tap, some actions are run, but that is not important in this context. First time I press, it handles the tap correctly. Second time it is running the code, but all View updates like showing a UIAlertView or showing a new view is delayed. But not delayed by time - It's waiting for me to touch the screen. No matter where I press or how long I wait, I just have to press. And it's every time but the first.

My TableView is set to single selection and not to show selection on touch. Any Ideas why it does this?

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
    if ([cell isKindOfClass:[DetailTableViewCell class]]) {
        DetailTableViewCell *detailCell = (DetailTableViewCell *)cell;
        NSString *hourString = [detailCell hourString];
        if (!detailCell.booking) {
            NSDate *rightNow = [NSDate new];
            NSDate *cellDate = [self.currentDate dateWithHour:indexPath.row andMinutes:0];
            // Only allow future bookings (but allow people people to book within the hour)
            if([rightNow compare:[cellDate nextHour]] == NSOrderedAscending){
                [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"roomBooking" sender:indexPath];
                return;
            } else {
                [[[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Error" message:@"We currently do not allow our users make bookings in the past" delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"Gotcha" otherButtonTitles:nil] show];
                return;
            }
        } else if ([detailCell.booking hasPhoneNumber]) {
            [[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"telprompt://%ld",(long)[detailCell.booking telephone]]]];
            return;
        } else {
            //TODO: FIND OUT IF BOOKING IS OWNED BY THE CURRENT USER
            [[[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Booking"
                                        message:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"You are now removing the booking at %@.", hourString]
                                       delegate:nil
                              cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:nil] show];
            @weakify(self);
            [self.room removeBookingWithId:[detailCell.booking.bookingId integerValue] andCompletion:^(BOOL success, NSError *error) {
                @strongify(self);
                if (success) {
                    @weakify(self);
                    [self.room.location updateBookingsWithCompletion:^(BOOL success, NSError *error) {
                        @strongify(self);
                        if (success) {
                            [self.calendar reloadData];
                        }
                    }];
                }
            }];
            return;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: How cells are constructed? Are there any recognizers inside cells or something similar?

Comment: That's going  to be a negative from here. There is no recognizers inside, nor anything I would expect to harm. The funny part is that It is actually reacting to touch normally. It's NSLogging the right stuff at the right time, but just not showing.

Comment: Well, then does this happen only after you remove booking(`self.room removeBookingWithId:`)? Check that `self.room.location updateBookingsWithCompletion:` executes completion block on main thread. This may be the reason.

Comment: It's happening no matter what code is run.

Comment: Then check that any reloadData or other UI related things are called on main thread. I believe it's reloadData called somewhere from other thread causes this.

Comment: Where is your tableView? inside a scrollview?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

SelectionStyle was set to None, but we changed it to something else, which solved the problem.

Click on the TableViewCell itself.
In your properties section locate: "Selection"
Set to: Blue/Grey/Default.